# Salesforce Api Immediately Fails After Login?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am logging in to salesforce via the username/password rest api.

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d \
   "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=xxx" -d \ 
   "client_secret=yyy" -d "username=username" -d \
   "password=paswordAndSecurityToken"

{
    "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/abc/123",
    "issued_at": "139342352341",
    "instance_url": "https://na12.salesforce.com",
    "signature": "zzz",
    "access_token": "xyz123"
}
```

Now I'd like to turn around and list available REST resources as described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/).  So I request

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer xyz123"
```

But I get the following

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

This suggests to me that the session id place after the word "Bearer" is more that the access_token.  How do I construct it?  If this is constructed correctly, why or how would I get invalid session id immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Its the access_token value from the token response, which appears to be what you're doing. But i notice that your token response says the instance is na12.salesforce.com, but your subsequent request is sent to na1, not na12. You have to send the request to the indicated instance. As na1 knowns nothing about your session (because its somewhere else) that would explain why you get the invalid session response from NA1.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I tried that but here's what I got `curl https://na12.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer xyz123"
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`

Comment: run curl with -v and sanity check what its actually sending.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is you have to use single quotes on unix, even though all of their examples use double quotes.  In other words, you have to use:

```
curl -v https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/ \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxyyzz!112233'
```

instead of (note the escaped !)

```
curl -v https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/ \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer xxyyzz\!112233"
```

Curl transmits the "\"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it by using quotes for token and \! instead of !

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/ \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "xyz\!123""
```

instead of

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/ \
-H "Authorization: Bearer xyz!123"
```